# Can a profile on a Razer Nostromo be carried over to another PC without Nostromo drivers or programming software?

Tags: keyboard

I would like to get myself a Nostromo for hotkeys (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, etc) so that I can increase my productivity at work, and type using the Dvorak keyboard layout (which is what I am already most proficient in) without having do deal with all the wonky keyboard shortcut remappings. I would also like to carry it between home and work without having to reprogram it (I won't be able to install the drivers or programming software on my work PC).

I checked the user guide, the vendor website, and all of the technical specs / FAQ and all I could find was that "macros are saved to my awesome PC." I'm fine with that, but what about key mappings? It doesn't say whether programmed key mappings are stored to the device and can run without drivers being installed if the hardware is plugged into a new PC. I recall also reading somewhere that the keypad can be used as a standard game controller without device-specific drivers installed, but again no mention on whether or not key mappings will work in this mode, or whether a profile saved to the device will work without drivers installed.

If anyone has one of these, can you let me know whether it is possible to use the Nostromo (and existing programmed key mappings) without having to install device software?

Thanks!

Comment: Better suited to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - no, the nostromo does not appear to work as a keyboard without drivers installed, and the profiles do not transfer between two PCs.